# SpringBoot 2.X: EmbeddedMongoServer bean is not Created

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to write integration test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses= MyRepository.class)
@DataMongoTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {EmbeddedMongoTestConfiguration.class,EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository ;

    @Test
    public void someTest(){

    }
}
```

Here is my configuration

```
@Configuration
public class EmbeddedMongoTestConfiguration {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
    public MongodProcess mongodProcess(MongodExecutable mongodExecutable) throws IOException {
        return mongodExecutable.start();
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
    public MongodExecutable mongodExecutable(MongodStarter mongodStarter, IMongodConfig iMongodConfig) throws IOException {
        return mongodStarter.prepare(iMongodConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public IMongodConfig mongodConfig() throws IOException {
        return new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.V3_6).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MongodStarter mongodStarter() {
        return MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

While running test I'm getting following Error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: 'mongo' depends on missing bean 'embeddedMongoServer'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'embeddedMongoServer' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'embeddedMongoServer' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:686)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    ... 35 more
```

Can some one tell me what I'm doing wrong here ??

### Fix

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(
        basePackageClasses = {
                MyRepository.class
        })
@Import({MongoProperties.class, EmbeddedMongoProperties.class})
public class EmbeddedMongoTestConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test";

    @Autowired
    private MongodStarter mongodStarter;

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return DATABASE_NAME;
    }

    @Bean
    public MongodStarter mongodStarter() {
        return MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
    }


    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        try {
            MongodExecutable mongodExecutable = mongodStarter.prepare(new MongodConfigBuilder()
                    .version(Version.V3_4_3)
                    .net(new Net("localhost", 12345, Network.localhostIsIPv6()))
                    .build());
            MongodProcess ngodProcess = mongodExecutable.start();
            return new MongoClient("localhost", 12345);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(EmbeddedMongoTestConfiguration.class)
@ContextConfiguration()
public class TprPoolRepositoryTest {......}
```

Comment: Where did you put mongo connection properties? I think you should also include annotation which points to a properties file.